# My Citations are not printing out as numbers and is not making a references section

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

Here is my code that I have for the beginning, however it wont reference to the references.bib, instead it just prints out the title in the paranthetical citation as ex. (marr_2019), without changing that to a number and referencing it at the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\begin{document}
```

Comment: Did you already compile your document with `biber`? See also [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/134144)

Comment: Aside: You should *under no circumstance* load both the `cite` and the `biblatex` package. They're mutually incompatible.

Comment: @leandriis how do I compiler with biber? It is not showing a question mark but according to the tutorials I have everything right.

Comment: I even deleted the use package cite since it is incompatible with biblatex